# Global method in Android App?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am very new to Android and I need my app to listen out for a specific key being pressed at all times. I have managed to get this working in each activity with the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F) {
        Log.d("Test","YOU PRESSED THE F KEY");
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
};
```

However, I am trying to figure out if I could just have this method once somewhere in the code? (Rather than have this piece of code in each individual activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new abstract activity which all of your activities can extend.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F) {
            Log.d("Test","YOU PRESSED THE F KEY");
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an abstract base class that extends Activity and overrides `dispatchKeyEvent` like you did, and then make all activities subclasses of this class.
Maybe you want to read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by first defining an abstract parent activity that holds this method and then inherit from this activity